# How to access a Group/Team mailbox using Microsoft Graph APIs

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there any way to get the folders of an O365 Group/Team using Graph APIs?
I know that for regular users or shared mailboxes, we can use this API Url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN/mailFolders
```

I also know that I can access the messages in the inbox of the Group/Team with this URL:

```
GET /groups/{id}/conversations
```

However, what I need to accomplish is to get the list of folders of the Group's mailbox and the item count of each folder. PS: The mailbox of a Group contains a folder called TeamChats where the chat conversations are stored and this is accessible through Powershell but I want to know if it's possible in Graph APIs.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for APIs to read channel messages?

Comment: Hi Wajeed. No, I am looking for an alternative to know how many messages there are in a channel without having to run a GetMessages (Which takes too long and very sensitive to throttling in case you have a large number of messages in the channel). This is possible through rhe mailbox in PowerShell. Do you have any leads if it is possible in Graph APIs?

Comment: Currently, there are no plans to support count as part of Graph APIs.